# Parallel processing with Java on desktop and mobile cpu's

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, cpu, multicore

I am developping a parallel processing code to solve an optimization problem.

First I try to run only one optimization job lets call it task(1). And then I try to run two copy of the same job in parallel task(2). Theoretically these two tasks will take same amount of time.

My question is that:

When i run these tasks on my i5 desktop computer task(1) and task(2) take same time to finish.
There is no problem with that. This is what i expected.

But when i use my i7 notebook, run(2) takes around %30 times more than run(1).
I do not understand this gap. Why two completely same parallel jobs takes %30 more time ?
Can it be a hardware difference between mobile and desktop cpus ?

Code and data are completely the same.

Only one difference is i7 notebook is 64 bit but i5 desktop is 32 bit.

Is there anybody has an idea or experience related to this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, AFAIK, Hardware plays major role (may cause inconsistency also) in threaded and parallel processing applications.

Comment: both are on same OS version? OS scheduals between processes, which runs when...

Comment: Both of them are windows7. Like i said desktop is 32, notebook is 64 bit.

Comment: i7 can range from 2 to 6 cores, while i5 have 2 or 4 cores. Scheduling also matters here, the two tasks may have equal runtime but for any reason T2 might be scheduled with a lower frequency.

Comment: If possible I will try to set thread priority manually. But it looks strange anyway. Because computer is not busy with any other task while doing this job. Everything else is closed. Maybe i must also try to use 32 bit java under 64 bit windows7.

Comment: @Baatar One idea -- are you using 32 bit JDK on the the desktop (32 bit) and 64 bit JVM on the netbook (64 bit).  If for example your using 32 bit JVM on a 64 bit machine then the 32 bit will be "emulated" thus adding some overhead.

Comment: @Baatar: although it's interesting to know why this happens, you should not try to do anything to make them run in the same amount of time. This is out of your control, and you should not rely on them running at the same speed. The only thing you should rely on is that each task will end up being executed.

Answer (score 1):

This might explain why the 64 bit version is running slow. [Java HotSpot VM FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/hotspotfaq-138619.html#64bit_performance)

> Generally, the benefits of being able to address larger amounts of memory come with a small performance loss in 64-bit VMs versus running the same application on a 32-bit VM.  This is due to the fact that every native pointer in the system takes up 8 bytes instead of 4.  The loading of this extra data has an impact on memory usage which translates to slightly slower execution depending on how many pointers get loaded during the execution of your Java program.  The good news is that with AMD64 and EM64T platforms running in 64-bit mode, the Java VM gets some additional registers which it can use to generate more efficient native instruction sequences.  These extra registers increase performance to the point where there is often no performance loss at all when comparing 32 to 64-bit execution speed.
>   The performance difference comparing an application running on a 64-bit platform versus a 32-bit platform on SPARC is on the order of 10-20% degradation when you move to a 64-bit VM.  On AMD64 and EM64T platforms this difference ranges from 0-15% depending on the amount of pointer accessing your application performs.

Comment: Thank you dk89. This is really a useful information. I will consider it. But this is not exact answer to my question. Because i do not compare 32bit run time with 64 bit run time. I compare 1 thread with 2 thread runs. They should theoretically take same amount of time. But in i7 notebook strangely there is a huge gap between two runs even though i use completely same code and data.

Comment: @Baatar are task 1 and task 2 the same?  Are they doing the same thing?  Some operations might be faster or slower in 64 bit.

Comment: Yes dk89. task1 and task2 are the same. Just task1 runs only one job with one thread, task2 runs two jobs with two threads. These two runs take same amount of time for i5 desktop. but on i7 notebook there is a gap (%30) between one and two threaded runs.

Comment: @Baatar do you mind posting the code?  I think its very interesting problem.

Comment: ahh it is really difficult dk89.. it is a quite complicated code requires many jar files.. but i will try different scenarios and let you know if i discover something..

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's due to the processor hardware, it seems that CPUs for mobile are slower than those for desktops. I've noticed a similar difference between my laptop (i7-2600 QM) and my desktop (i7-2600), where running the same parallel job in Java takes 33% less time on the desktop computer.

Comment: Thank you Lolo. Actually my problem is not the run time difference between desktop and notebook. My problem is that, on desktop i can run aforementioned two tasks with same amount of time. But when i run these tasks on notebook there is a gap between two runs. This is not a comparison between mobile and desktop cpus.